# How to pass content of one iterators to another in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have two lists `a = {1,2,2,5,6,6,6,7}` and `b = {2,3,3,6,6,6,8}`
I want to get the equivalent elements, in this case, the output should be 2 *(2 = 2) and 9 * (6 = 6) Here is part of my code

```
    Iterator aIt = a.iterator();
    Iterator bIt = b.iterator();
    Iterator tempIt = b.iterator();

    int aNode = (Integer)aIt.next();
    int bNode = (Integer)bIt.next();
    Boolean isEquals = false;

    while(aIt.hasNext()||bIt.hasNext()){
        while(aNode<bNode){
            aNode = (Integer)aIt.next();
        }
        while(aNode>bNode){
            bNode = (Integer)bIt.next();
        }
        while(aNode==bNode){
            tempIt = bIt;
            while(aNode==bNode){
                System.out.println(aNode + " = " + bNode);
                bNode = (Integer)tempIt.next();
            }
            aNode = (Integer)aIt.next();
            tempIt = bIt;
            bNode = (Integer)tempIt.next();
            isEquals = true;
        }
        if(isEquals){
            bIt = tempIt;
            isEquals = false;
        }
    }
```

However after I run the code I realise that what I pass is the reference of `bIt` to `tempIt` not the content. Is there any solution if I really want to use iterator to achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand how you get from a, b to `(1,0) (2,0) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) (5,3)` - What data manipulation do you want to do?

Comment: @assylias these are indexes. read carefully.

Comment: could you explain, then, deporter, because it's not clear to me, either?

Comment: @deporter I've been staring at it for 2 minutes - still don't get it...

Comment: @andrewcooke (1,0) means a[1] = b[0] and so on. did you get it?

Comment: could it be something like: for the unique integers in the union of the two sets, ordered, return their indices in the input lists, numbered from 1, with 0 for missing?  (it's critical that the inputs are ordered)

Comment: @deporter Ok got it - but question has changed so I think I'm going to give up on that one!!

Comment: the guava library has some useful utilities for iterables and iterators, which is where i would start if i were going to do this.

Comment: @assylias Sorry about that, I just edit my question. Hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to clone your iterator, something that is not supported in Java (the   `clone()` method is private). 
Just as a note, the iterator does not contain the data, you should think of it as an interface to the list. So maybe iterators is not the most ideal solution here.

Comment: +1.  Keep track of the indices yourself and the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that there's an easier way to do it---namely, not using iterators, but rather by using the lists themselves.

So if your lists A and B are `ArrayList<Integer>`s, it might look something like this:

```
public void printMatch(ArrayList<Integer> A, ArrayList<Integer> B) {
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < B.length(); j++) {
            if(A.get(i).equals(B.get(j))) {
                System.out.println("Match!" + A.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or something along those lines---I've not compiled that, but it's the right idea.

Comment: wtf?  this just detects if any value appears in both lists.  that's not what was asked (neither in the first not the revised question).